# Why does N64 screen go black after 1 or 2 hours of playing?

Tags: nintendo-64, super-mario-64

I bought a used N64. I can play Mario 64 for 1 or 2 hours normally, but after this time, colours of the game slowly change to green and brown, and finally black screen appear. I don't know what's happening.

What can I do to avoid this issue?

Comment: What do you need to do to play again? Turn it off and back on?

Answer (score 2):

Probably overheating, most likely you are playing with the console on carpet and it's blocking the vent holes on the bottom of the console. The N64 generally runs very cool anyway so it takes a long time to overheat.